# How to add static resource location for files from server but different that server where app is

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, static-content

Im building spring-boot 2 App and want to know if i can and how to add static resources location for the server files but different that server where app is.

Im using application.properties file to set my resource location. Its not a problem for files from disk.

```
spring.resources.static-locations= file:/dir1/fileWithVideo/, file:/http://ip:port/home/seleco/video
```

It works for disk files but not for servers and how make it works

Answer (score 0):

To get the from servers location dynamically use this in application.properties.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:${app.config.dir:./directory location on server}/file name
```

Comment: i need files from different server than where app is. Is it possible?

Comment: NO, its not possible, as to get files from another server you need to connect to that server, and copy it from there to here, these all things are not possible in application.properties. my suggestion is to separate logic for getting files from another server and use it where your application is running.